# Nested try-finally blocks, equivalence and guarantees in Java

Tags: java, error-handling, nested, try-catch-finally, try-finally

Recently I was working on a "cleanup" method and I wanted to make sure that each statement is attempted to be executed. My first approach was something like this (where `s#;` are statements):

```java
try {
    s1;
} finally {
    try {
        s2;
    } finally {
        s3;
    }
}
```

For simplicity I have omitted the exception handling part here (the `catch` blocks), where I store the first occurring and subsequent suppressed `Throwable`s to rethrow later.

Then I noticed that there is another (maybe more correct?) way to do the same thing:

```java
try {
    try {
        s1;
    } finally {
        s2;
    }
} finally {
    s3;
}
```

In my opinion the second approach *feels* more correct because as soon as `s1;` is attempted, we are already inside both `try` blocks, which guarantees that all `finally` blocks will be executed.

My question is: Is there actually a difference between those approaches in terms of guarantees that the JVM provides?

Also is it theoretically possible that an `Error` is thrown by the JVM in the first code example at `// not a statement` (see code below), such that the inner `try`-`finally` block isn't attemped anymore?

```java
try {
    s1;
} finally {
    // not a statement
    try {
        s2;
    } finally {
        s3;
    }
}
```

According to [11.1.3. Asynchronous Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.1.3), exceptions can be thrown basically anywhere. This is the main reason why I think that nesting the `try`-`finally` blocks is necessary as shown in the second code example. Or do I understand the JLS wrong and exceptions can only occur if there is also a statement?

Comment: Looking at the byte code produced might help answer your questions, and also the language spec.

Comment: This is not 'all or none at all'. This is 'all'.

Answer (score 1):

Add an `s4` and an `s5` into the mix and it becomes even clearer than it already should be that this is a hard to maintain mess that requires comments explaining why you've got this bizarro mix of nested try blocks.

Hence, I suggest you do this instead:

```
Throwable t = null;
try { s1(); } catch (Throwable e) {t = e;}
try { s2(); } catch (Throwable e) {t = e;}
try { s3(); } catch (Throwable e) {t = e;}
if (t != null) throw t;
```

You can fancy that up some and replace `t = e;` with a utility method (`t = update(t, e);`) which, if an exception has already occurred, will attach them as suppressed exceptions just like how try-finally does it.

Or, even nicer, add lambda support:

```
public final class Cleanup {
  public interface CleanupJob<T extends Throwable> {
    void cleanup() throws T;
  }

  @SafeVarargs
  public static <T extends Throwable> void cleanup(CleanupJob<? extends T>... jobs) {
    Throwable ex = null;
    for (var job : jobs) try {
      job.cleanup();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      if (ex == null) {
        ex = e;
      } else {
        ex.addSuppressed(e);
      }
    }

    if (ex != null) throw (T) ex;
  }
}
```

To use:

```
import static CleanupRunner.cleanup;

...

cleanup(
() -> s1(),
() -> s2(),
() -> s3(),
() -> s4());

// or even

cleanup(
  this::s1,
  ref::s2,
  SomeClass::staticS3
);
```

> Also is it theoretically possible that an Error is thrown by the JVM in the first code example at // not a statement (see code below), such that the inner try block isn't attemped anymore?

It is not.

Comment: "It is not." Do you have any evidence for this (e.g. from the JLS)? To me it seems like that the JLS says that exceptions can happen basically everywhere. See JLS 11.1.3. Asynchronous Exceptions: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.1.3. This is exactly the reason why I'm asking this question. Otherwise I wouldn't have nested the `try`-`finally` blocks but I would have done the same thing as in your first code example.

Comment: You're asking me to prove a negative. Which is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I wanted to make sure that each statement is attempted to be executed (either all or none at all). ..."*

To preface, with the provided examples, all of the statements will be executed.
There would be no, *"... or none at all"*.

Utilize a *boolean*, here is an example.

```java
boolean exit = false;
try {
        
} catch (Throwable t) {
    exit = true;
} finally {
    if (!exit) {
        try {

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            exit = true;
        } finally {
        
        }
    }
}
```

Typically, a *finally* code-block is used to simply apply a final procedure.
Which, in some cases is actually necessary, e.g., closing a *[Closeable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Closeable.html)* object.
And realistically, this is why the *[AutoCloseable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html)* interface, and the *[try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)* syntax, was implemented.

```java
int value;
try {
    value = Integer.parseInt("abc");
} finally {
    value = 123;
}
```

In other-words, while your code is permissible, and valid, you typically would not want to keep nesting the *try* code-blocks.
Simply re-evaluate your current *design* and *[control-flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow)*.

> *"... Then I noticed that there is another (maybe more correct?) way to do the same thing ..."*

Correct, this example will provide the same functionality.
And, I imagine the *interpreter* would compile a similar *"[bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode)"*, for each.

> *"... Is there actually a difference between those approaches in terms of guarantees that the JVM provides? ..."*

The guarantees would be the same; the abstraction is the same.
Each *finally* block will be executed, regardless of whether a *Throwable* is thrown or not; unlike the *catch* block.

> *"... is it theoretically possible that an `Error` is thrown by the JVM in the first code example ... such that the inner `try` block isn't attemped anymore? ..."*

Similarly, if an *Error* is thrown at that line, any subsequent code would not be executed.
The program will simply halt and exit.
You would need to place that code within a *try-catch* block as well.

```java
try {

} finally {
    try {
        throw new Error();
    } finally {

    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't really find an answer to my actual question in your answer. I have edited my question, to make my actual point a bit clearer and to explain why I think nesting is necessary. "You would need to place that code within a *try-catch* block as well." The point is, there is no code at this place and the question is, can the JVM still throw an error at this place. If so, this would contradict with your answer, that my two examples are equivalent. Also, I'm aware what happens, when an exception is thrown. That was not my question.

Comment: @stonar96, a _Throwable_ needs to originate from something in the code.